# Cut text in multiselect list FIREFOX, SAFARI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

I have this problem:
I'm using multiselect list for options, and when the text is to long I cut it.

```
white-space: nowrap;
overflow-x: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Now here is the problem: in firefox list disables scroll on keys, while using that CSS. What I mean is that you can still scroll with mouse, but the list won't scroll if you select options with up and down keys, it will go out of bounds... While on Chrome it works properly. And Safari doesn't cut the text... Is there any way to fix this? I'm actually use Meteor and ng-option.

```css
body{
  scrollbar-base-color: #C0C0C0;
  scrollbar-base-color: #C0C0C0;
  scrollbar-3dlight-color: #C0C0C0;
  scrollbar-highlight-color: #C0C0C0;
  scrollbar-track-color: #EBEBEB;
  scrollbar-arrow-color: black;
  scrollbar-shadow-color: #C0C0C0;
  scrollbar-dark-shadow-color: #C0C0C0;
}

.testSelectList  {
  width: 100px;
}
.testSelectListOption {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar { width: 0px; height: 0px;}
::-webkit-scrollbar-button {  background-color: #666; }
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {  background-color: #999;}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece { background-color: #ffffff;}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb { height: 0px; background-color: #666; border-radius: 0px;}
::-webkit-scrollbar-corner { background-color: #999;}}
::-webkit-resizer { background-color: #666;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<select class="testSelectList" multiple="multiple" size="6" >
  <option class="testSelectListOption">11111111111111111111111111111111111111111</option>
  <option class="testSelectListOption">22222222222222222222222222222222222222222</option>
  <option class="testSelectListOption">33333333333333333333333333333333333333333</option>
  <option class="testSelectListOption">44444444444444444444444444444444444444444</option>
  <option class="testSelectListOption">55555555555555555555555555555555555555555</option>
  <option class="testSelectListOption">66666666666666666666666666666666666666666</option>
  <option class="testSelectListOption">77777777777777777777777777777777777777777</option>
  <option class="testSelectListOption">88888888888888888888888888888888888888888</option>
  <option class="testSelectListOption">99999999999999999999999999999999999999999</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Could you make a fiddle with the issue?

Comment: @Forty , Something like that.